# How To Enable HTTPS SSL On Existing C# .Net 4.6.2 Web Service on IIS7

Tags: c#, ssl, https, iis-7, .net-4.6

I am attempting to enable SSL/HTTPS on our existing web services within our solution. I have selected Require SSL on the application within IIS7 and have set https bindings for the whole website (localhost, port 443, *) and attached a valid test certificate. I've also copied these settings to our live server for further testing but using a legitimate certificate. I can view the normal .aspx pages over HTTPS on both servers.

The problem comes when I visit https://servername/basewebservices/message.svc/GetBasket and instead of receiving the usual json response I get on http I get a 404.0 error. I can't seem to get around this. I've tried various settings in my web.config without any joy at all.

I have attempted to set up a brand new web service but still can't get the https to work. It would be amazing to either get my current service working or maybe be pointed to a foolproof, walkthrough of how to setup a (ideally not MVC) secure web service.

I have a default.aspx in BaseWebServices which shows up on http and https. I've noticed that https://localhost/basewebservices/Message.svc shows the default message service page. Adding the /GetBasket to the url presents me with the 404 error.

I'll include the code for the BaseWebServices project from our solution:

**IMessage.cs**

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;

    namespace BaseWebServices
    {
        // NOTE: The interface name "IMessage" here must match the references to "IMessage" in Web.config.
        // NOTE 2: Parameters must be string data type when using UriTemplate
        [ServiceContract]
        public interface IMessage
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [WebInvoke(
                Method = "GET",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
                UriTemplate = "GetBasket")]
            List<BasketItemDTO> GetBasket();
        }
    }
```

**Message.svc**

```
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
    using System.Text;

    namespace BaseWebServices
    {
        // NOTE: If you change the class name "Message" here, you must also update the reference to "Message" in Web.config and in the associated .svc file.
        [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
        public class Message : IMessage
        {
            private string DBConn { get; set; }

            public Message()
            {
                DBConn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConn"];
            }

            public List<BasketItemDTO> GetBasket()
            {
                try
                {
                    var customerController = new BaseWeb.BaseCustomer.CustomerController(DBConn);
                    int customerId = customerController.GetCustomerIdFromCookie();

                    if (customerId != 0)
                    {
                        var shoppingCartController = new ShoppingCartController(DBConn);
                        var result = shoppingCartController.GetShoppingCart((int)customerId);
                        return result;
                    }
                    else
                        return new List<BasketItemDTO>();
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }

            }
    }
```

**web.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <configuration>
        <appSettings/>
        <connectionStrings/>

        <system.web>
            <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
            <authentication mode="Forms"/>
            <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
        </system.web>

        <system.serviceModel>
            <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
              multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
            <diagnostics>
              <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
            </diagnostics>

            <services>
                <service behaviorConfiguration="BaseWebServices.MessageBehavior"
                name="BaseWebServices.Message">
                    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
                      name="webEndPoint" contract="BaseWebServices.IMessage" /> 

                    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                    </service>

                    <service behaviorConfiguration="BaseWebServices.MessageBehavior"
                    name="BaseWebServices.Service">

                    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="httpBinding" name="webEndPoint" contract="BaseWebServices.IService" />

                    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="httpsBinding" name="httpsEndPoint" contract="BaseWebServices.IService" />

                    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                </service>
            </services>

            <bindings>
                <webHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="httpBinding" allowCookies="false">
                      <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
                      </security>
                    </binding>
                    <binding name="httpsBinding" allowCookies="false">
                      <security mode="Transport"/>
                    </binding>
                </webHttpBinding>
            </bindings>

            <behaviors>
                <endpointBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="webBehavior">
                      <webHttp />
                    </behavior>
                    <behavior name="wsHttpBinding" />
                    <behavior name="BaseWebServices.TestSVCAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                      <enableWebScript />
                    </behavior>
                </endpointBehaviors>

                <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior name="BaseWebServices.MessageBehavior">
                        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
                        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                    </behavior>
                </serviceBehaviors>
            </behaviors>

        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Any help or pointing out the obvious fact I've overlooked would be hugely appreciated. I spent all day yesterday attempting various configurations to get this working. This is my first SO posting so if I've done something daft point it out and I'll put it right.

Comment: Can you put a default.aspx page under this site and try to browse that and see if that works.

Comment: Hi. It works on http and https as expected.